# Round function with multiple inputs not working in MATLAB function block in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to round a number to 3 decimal places. In MATLAB I can easily do it in this way:

```
>> number=25.0001;
>> round(25.0001,3)

ans =

25
```

If I try to do this in Simulink in a MATLAB Function block in this way:

```
function D_avg1 = fcn(m)
%#codegen

D_avg1 = round(m,3);
```

It gives error:

```
Error calling 'round'. This call-site passes more inputs to this function than it can accept.
Function 'BSD_System /Averaging/MATLAB Function' (#278.45.55), line 4, column 10:
"round(m,3)"
Component: MATLAB Function | Category: Coder error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the answer. Just do this:

```
function D_avg1 = fcn(m)
%#codegen

D_avg1 = round((m*1000)/1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB Function block only supports the syntax with one input for `round` function. See documentation for list of functions at http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--alphabetical-list.html where against `round` function you will see "Supports only the syntax Y = round(X)."

As smyslov mentions you need to make it extrinsic if you need this syntax. But extrinsic works only for simulation. For embedded code generation extrinsic functions will not generate any code.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably include `eml.extrinsic('round')` in your embedded matlab function. I had similar issues and for whatever MATLAB functions I was using, I include them in the `eml.extrinsic('')` would resolve the issue, like so:

```
function D_avg1 = fcn(m)
%#codegen

eml.extrinsic('round');

D_avg1 = round(m,3);
```

Now it should work as far as I know.

Comment: Careful when using `extrinsic` function calls, the data returned is of the `mxArray` data type.